# Terraform: Issues creating aws_lb with aws_subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working through some Terraform code designed to deploy a VPC, create public and private subnets, and then create load balancers, ECS containers, etc.  My VPC creation works fine, but I'm running into an issue in creating my application load balancers.

My code is divided into a couple of different modules.  The VPC module creates public subnets like this:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count  = length(var.public_subnet_cidr_blocks)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.primary_vpc.id
    
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)]
    
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_cidr_blocks[count.index]
    
  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet"
  }
}
```

I've defined 2 CIDR blocks for the Public subnet, and in my output I see that it creates 2 subnets in 2 different Availability Zones.

My Load Balancer module then as an `aws_subnets` datasource to pull in the details of the Public subnets:

```
data "aws_subnets" "public" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
    
  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet"
  }
}
```

My problem is when I try to create an `aws_lb` resource using this code:

```
resource "aws_lb" "keycloak" {
  name               = "my-lb"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = false
    
  subnets         = data.aws_subnets.public.ids
  
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
}
```

The `plan` operation goes fine, but when I run the `apply` I get the following error message:

> │ Error: creating ELBv2 application Load Balancer (my-lb): ValidationError: At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified

The output shows that my Public subnets are in 2 different availability zones.  If I do an output of my `aws_subnets.public` data source I can see the subnet IDs that I am expecting.  In fact, if I hard-code the subnet IDs in my code it works just fine (example):

```
resource "aws_lb" "keycloak" {
  name               = "my-lb"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = false
    
  subnets = [
    "subnet-XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "subnet-YYYYYYYYYYY",
  ]
     
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
}
```

Why is it that using an `aws_subnets` datasource for my subnet lookup is not working here?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try adding `dependes_on = [ aws_subnet.public ]` to the `aws_subnets` data source?

Comment: I think you are not using the filter in the proper way. If you want all the subnets with tag "Public Subnet" then you need to write the filter as: `filter { name   = "tag:Name" values = ["Public Subnet"]}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer, as I'm sure you are trying to use the count index to distribute amongst available "availability zones."

Andres Bores response about the dependency is correct.  There is a dependency on the public subnets being created before we can grab the subnet data.

The data returned by `data "aws_subnets" "public"` is a list. Terraform resource alb is simply using only the first entry in the list returned by the data.

There is probably a method to use the count.index, which would be better than the following code. The following code does work because it declares the first and second in the list as the subnets to utilize.

```
data "aws_subnets" "foobar" {
  tags = {
    Name  = "public subnet"
  }
depends_on = [aws_subnet.public-subnets]
  
}
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "my-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = [data.aws_subnets.foobar.ids[0],data.aws_subnets.foobar.ids[1]]
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.alb-sg.id}"]
}
output "aws_alb" {
  value = aws_lb.alb.id
}
```

PS.  I tested the above before posting

Comment: So -- I think -- the problem with this would be the fact that aws_subnets.public is in a separate module, so I can't have a depends_on.  The output of that module is what I was using in my data.aws_subnets.public lookup in a different module.